# How to replicate data from my local phpmyadmin mysql database to godaddy cpanel mysql database?

Tags: html, mysql, database

I am having a MySQL database in my local machine (in XAMPP) that I access using phpmyadmin. I also have a website hosted on Godaddy. I generally stay offline and make changes into data stored into database.

I want to know how can I auto replicate the changes in local database to the one in Godaddy's server or can replicate using click of a button.

I have seen some answers that told about replication but I am unable to replicate data from my local machine to the Godaddy's server.

Can anyone please tell me the steps to replicate database in simplest way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you find anything Vikash ?

Comment: @Dawoodjee I went through lot of stuff and came to the below conclusion

Comment: Is that a manual process? If thats an option you can also: 1. export data as sql INSERT statements in phpmyadmin from the source and 2. run the sql query(s) on the target DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of searching and learning, I finally found an answer to this question.

**On shared hosting, Godaddy do not provide access to the configuration files of mysql (my.ini).** So the replication of data is not possible using master slave replication from local(master) to remote(slave) MySQL.

The only thing that can be done is, one can create a log file of all the data that are being entered into database while the user is offline (maybe a XML file) which contains the data that is not transfered to the global database, and can upload the file when connected to the internet and parse the XML to send data to the global database.